# what's the simplest way to escape Javascript sequences that would result in undesired functionality if embedded in the script tags of HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I recently worked on a project that required me to read javascript code from .js files and embed it inside the script tags of HTML code. I thought this was a trivial task, until I learned that some sequences that cause no problems inside a .js file, can result in undesired functionality if embedded inside the script tags of an HTML file.

For example, if a .js file with valid javascript code contains sequences such as:

```
/*
    ...comments...
    Add the following to your HTML:
    <script language="javascript" src="samplejs.js"></script>
    ...comments...
 */
```

...then those sequences, when embedded inside the script tag of an HTML file, will cause problems when the interpreter hits the line

```
"<script language="javascript" src="samplejs.js"></script>"
```

(At least this is the case in Firefox.)

Since the regex...

```
"\<script.*\>.*\</script\>"
```

...will catch script tags even if they appear as part of string literals. ie:

```
document.write('<div><script>doSomething()</script></div>')
```

...is the solution to the problem a more robust regex (something along the lines of

```
"/\*.*\<.*\>.*\</.*\>.*\*/"
```

...), or a different approach?

(Assume that stripping out all the comments is not an option)

Comment: You could simply strip out all comments.

Comment: the question about where and when the process of making »script ready« is quiet important. If you can process it serverside you have much more abilities, otherwise there also exist whole js parsers written in js which can prepare the script for you...

Comment: When you say "some sequences", it's actually just this specific case where you have a closing script tag in the comments, right?

Comment: also, could you explain how you embed the code? The standard way would be to do an eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest as in least effort for you? I'd run it through a minifier such as UglifyJS on the way in, which should remove comments among other things.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a reason to read files via ajax and writing them into `<script>` tags, but it should be no problem at all if you use the correct methods (such as [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode) or assigning to the `text`/[`textConent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent)/`innerText` properties).

If you are however using `document.write`, you would of course need to escape any HTML in it. That means replacing `<>&"` with their respective entities.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just replace all instances of `</script>` with `\u003C/script>`? In theory this wouldn't affect the strings (since `'\u003C' == '<'`), but it'd prevent the browser from misinterpreting the comments (`/*\u003C/script>*/` wouldn't end the script block prematurely).

Since it appears this is all automated, I'm assuming that "mangling" the occasional string a bit is not going to cause any heartburn.